# Get folder list of files with specific system permissions

Tags: bash

I have hundreds of subdirectories and I have to find out every subdirectory that has files with a specific system permission (in this case 0755).

I'm trying to achieve that with:

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -perm 0775 -printf '%h\n' | wc -l
```

This command shows multiple times the same directory name, I would need to display only one occurrence for each directory.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `type f` shows only files but `type d` only directories.

Comment: Can you add some example output of what you are getting and what you would like to see?

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type f -perm 0775 -printf '%h\n' | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

You search about files with `type f` and print only the directories of this files with %h. That is not what you need. Search about directories with `-type d` and delete the printf option complete.

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -perm 0775 | wc -l
```